# How do I build a binary tree in Java using this method?

Tags: java, function, recursion, binary-tree, nodes

I have a recursive Java method that builds a binary tree:

```
BT build() {
   return(a[++k] == 0 ? null : new BT(build(), build()));
}
```

BT is a class that looks like this:

```
class BT {
  BT L; BT R;
  BT(BT l, BT r) { 
      L = l; R = r; 
  }
}
```

How does the build class work? If I wanted to build a tree with N nodes, then how many times would the build function be called in terms of N?

Comment: `build` class? Do you mean `build` function?

Comment: Also, `a` and `k` are never passed as arguments and are not declared. I'm assuming those are class variables you haven't shown?

Comment: This very much seems like homework from a college / university course on recursion and code complexity, and some parts of the assignment (a, k) have been left out.

Answer (score 1):

Each call of the `build` function either creates a node or returns null.

There are always N+1 null pointers in a binary tree with N nodes. This is because each node has 2 outgoing edges and each node, except the root, has one incoming edge.

This gives 2*N+1 calls of `build` to create a tree with N nodes.

Comment: @33ted since k is incremented exactly once per call of `build` this should not be too difficult to work out ;-)